# Convert  to %F0 %9F %8C %A0

Tags: delphi, unicode, unicode-escapes

I know  is %F0 %9F %8C %A0

but how can I convert this to be usable in Delphi ?

I tried several html encoders , but none give this result

my test

```
 for i := 1 to length(s) do
    result:= result+IntToHex(ord(s[i]),2);
```

but my result is D83CDF20

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about your set up. What, *exactly*, do you want to achieve?

Comment: Putting `%F0%9F%8C%A0` in an HTML document will just give you the literal `%F0%9F%8C%A0`. What you're looking for isn't HTML encoding, that's why searching for HTML encoders didn't produce anything useful. Hint: what do you want to use this for? What might you call such an encoding, then?

Comment: i need to send with this encoding , the server waits for her.
look my test
  for i := 1 to length(s) do
    result:= result+inttostr(ord(s[i]));
@MartynA

Comment: CP8 M: Perhaps you are looking to *URL* (not HTML) encode a string.

Comment: Then put that in your q.  Readers shouldn't have to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please don't fight us. Please tell us the back story, and let us tell you the right way to solve your problem. Please trust me when I tell you that you don't know how to solve it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a simple UTF-8 encoding of this character. You can get the Delphi string using `TEncoding` like this:

```
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(TBytes.Create($F0, $9F, $8C, $A0));
end;
```

or simply

```
S := '';
```

In case you want it the other way round:

```
var
  bytes: TBytes;
begin
  bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('');
end;
```

Or:

```
var
  S: UTF8String;
begin
  S := UTF8String('');
end;
```

Valid for Delphi 2009 and later.